# Develop .net core on windows and deploy on azure app service for linux

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, azure-app-service-envrmnt

I want to develop a mvc application in .net core 2.0 in visual studio on Windows and deploy it on azure app service for Linux. 
How to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

On azure, create your appService

On visual studio :
In the top menu :

Build

-> Publish [SolutionName]
-> select Create

-> at the bottom, click on the cursor near "immediate publish" and select "create profile"

-> Change the hosting plan to target your app service

Comment: Thank you. I did that. It worked successfully but the url still shows the default app service page and not the application which I published.

Comment: And before this code, other pages were accessible ?

Comment: Yes. After I published my application, the application shows the default content which were there when I created the web app. I also checked the ftp location, it has the dll's and view's I published.